# Explanation of shopping carts and webshops

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152302/shopping-cart-ideas) concerning creating a shopping cart. It seems maybe I am misusing the phrase "shopping cart" or maybe the people that answered didn't understand the post well.

I understand that open source software like "Magento, OpenCart, Prestashop etc.." are called shopping carts.

I also understand that paid hosting services like "Shopify, BigCommerce, 3dCart etc.." are also called shopping carts. Am I wrong?

Both the open source and the paid  hosting services gives you the admin panel that you use to create your own shopping site.

I also understand that "Yii, CakePHP, Symphony, Zend etc.." are frameworks for creating whatever you want.

Is there a difference between "shopping carts" and "web shops". For me I see them as the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shopping cart is a module of a web shop used for holding items waiting to be ordered in a place where the user can keep track of them.

A web shop is Amazon, ebuyer, or some other shopping site.

Magento is actually classed as eCommerce software which is umbrella term for what you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question:  "...*hosting services* like "Shopify, BigCommerce, 3dCart etc..".  These are **services** that *offer* a shopping cart.  And Webshops are pretty much an implementation of shopping carts.  Your whole onlnine store is the webshop, and the mechanism to choose products and purchase them is the shopping cart of that.  The likes of "Magento, OpenCart, Prestashop" are eCommerce typically *packages* that include a shopping Cart that you would use as part of your "webstore".  The whole eCommerce solution also includes things like order reports, customer reports, administrative features, etc.